# AS3 duplicate dynamic text

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, text, duplicates

Trying to find out how could i duplicate this function! So i have a code fetching simple text data from xml file named text1.xml. On my stage there is scrolling text wich tells site info but i need another scrooling text with little smaller font placed just above first on that tells something different, so would i need another xml file with text in it like text2.xml?. How to upgrade this, here is the code:

```
//SCROLLING SPEED
var scrolling_speed:int = 7;
//TEXT TO SCROLL
var text_to_scroll:String = "Main site info like:www.mysite.com";

var xmlLoader: URLLoader = new URLLoader();
var myData: XML;
var myItems: XMLList;
var position: uint;
xmlLoader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onComplete);
xmlLoader.load(new URLRequest("text1.xml"));

function onComplete(e : Event): void{
    myData = new XML(URLLoader(e.currentTarget).data);
    myItems = myData..item;
}


//establish the field
var my_text:TextField = new TextField();
//add the field to stage
addChild(my_text);
//set the text
my_text.text = text_to_scroll;
//set the x coord off right side of stage
my_text.x = stage.stageWidth;
//set y coord in middle of stage (about)
my_text.y = (stage.stageHeight/1)-(my_text.height/2.5);
//not selectable
my_text.selectable = false;
//no border
my_text.border = false;
//field scales with more text
my_text.autoSize = TextFieldAutoSize.LEFT;

//set a format
var my_text_format:TextFormat = new TextFormat();
//set the color to the hex
my_text_format.color = 0x000000;
//set the font size
my_text_format.size = 28;
//set the font face
my_text_format.font = "Futura Md BT";
//apply formatting
my_text.defaultTextFormat = my_text_format;
my_text.setTextFormat(my_text_format);

//add the listener to scroll
my_text.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME,move_text);

//scroll function
function move_text(myevent:Event):void {
    my_text.x-=scrolling_speed;
    if(my_text.x<-my_text.width){
        my_text.x=stage.stageWidth;
        //Set next text
        if(++position >= myItems.length()){
            position = 0;
        }
        my_text.text = myItems[position];
    }
}
```

And the xml(text1) file for text look like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<data>

    <news>
        <item><![CDATA[Text for news 1]]></item>
        <item><![CDATA[Text for news 2]]></item>
        <item><![CDATA[Text for news 3]]></item>
        <item><![CDATA[Text for news 4]]></item>
        <item><![CDATA[Text for news 5]]></item>
        <item><![CDATA[Text for news 6]]></item>
    </news>
</data>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why would you need another xml file? You already have data source, so it's not a problem to add additional information to the xml you have.

Extend XML with necessary information:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<data>

    <news>
        <item><![CDATA[Text for news 1]]></item>
        <item><![CDATA[Text for news 2]]></item>
        <item><![CDATA[Text for news 3]]></item>
        <item><![CDATA[Text for news 4]]></item>
        <item><![CDATA[Text for news 5]]></item>
        <item><![CDATA[Text for news 6]]></item>
    </news>

    <anotherData>
            <info><![CDATA[Text for small sized text]]></info>
    </anotherData>
</data>
```

Place your text field and apply text to it:

```
//initialise text field with format, position, etc
mySmallTextField.text = myData.anotherData.info;
```

And scroll it

```
function move_text(myevent:Event):void {
    //your code for my_text

    mySmallTextField.x = -someSpeed;
    if(mySmallTextField.x < -mySmallTextField.width){
        mySmallTextField.x = stage.stageWidth;
    }
}
```

Comment: having some errors i wrote what i done with the code

Comment: Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference.

Comment: But you just copied my code, without even analysing it... did you read comments in the code?

Comment: still getting some errors dont know where i go wrong

Comment: Errors in flash are very descriptive.

Comment: i posted another question:(